# How to install firmware-mod-kit in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

i'm newbie in Ubuntu. 
after installation Ubuntu 14.04 , i want to install firmware-mod-kit  tar.gz but i don't do that.  explain me step by step command to install for tar.gz , please.

Comment: What should you do? Play! Jump! Shoot at your jealous friends :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. At first use `tar -zxvf firmware-mod-kit tar.gz` or you can extract by right click on it and click extract here.
2. Then go inside of newly created folder where the file is extracted.
3. Make sure you first read a file called INSTALL or INSTALL.txt or README. Check if there is any of these files with the ls command, and then display the right one with:

   ```
   xdg-open INSTALL
   ```

The file will contain the right indications to go on with the compiling process. Usually the three "classical" steps are:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You may also need to install some dependencies, generally after some configure error which will tell you what you are missing. You can also use checkinstall instead of make install.

See here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but it's prominent in Google.. specifically for fmk, you untar it; there's all these shell scripts (.sh files) that perform the kit's various functions.  They build source as needed -- gcc spits out a lot of warnings but it builds.  I had to install python-magic.